# Activemq in C++

Tags: c++, activemq-classic

I was trying to find a C++ equivalent of ActiveMQ, a queuing system that is used as an MQTT broker in Pub-Sub Model in MQTT.

I am trying to get an C++ equivalent of ActiveMQ(Java) that can be used as per that targeted platform.

https://activemq.apache.org/cms/  -> this can be used to communicate between ActiveMQ(java) and C++

Will I be able to replace the ActiveMQ-Java with the above one?

Answer (score 0):

CMS is C++ equivalent of JMS(java) so you may use either of them (or may both) since they work the same way with exactly similar functionality.
To implement publish subscribe, you need to subscribe to a topic instead of a queue, C++ code would be something similar to the following;

```
    Connection* connection;
    Session* session;
    MessageConsumer* consumer;
    Destination* channel;
    MessageProducer* producer;

    connection = connectionFactory->createConnection();
    session= connection->createSession(Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    // this acts like a bulletin board,multiple consumer can subscribe to Topic instead of a Queue
    channel= session->createTopic(producer); 
     // channel = session->createQueue(producer);
```

Hope that helps